# Certain principle bundle structure on $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \{0\}$

Tags: manifolds, group-actions, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Is there a right action of $\mathbb{H}^{2}$  on some  $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \{0\}$  such that this action gives us  a principle fibre  bundle.

Here $\mathbb{H}^{2}$  is the Poincare upper plane  with its standard non abelian Lie group  structure

Comment: How is the upper plane a non-abelian Lie group? EDIT: do you identify it with the orientation preserving affine automorphisms of the real line $\Bbb R$? Both are homeomrphic to $\Bbb R^*_+\times \Bbb R$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat  each element $(a,b)\in \mathbb{H}^{2}$  is  counted  as  a linear(affine) map on $\mathbb{R}$ with $t \to bt+a$.The group operation is "composition" In the language of group theory it is the semidirect product $\mathbb{R} \rtimes \mathbb{R}^{+}$. I learned the first interpretation from the book of  De Carmo Riemannian geometry.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan   If I am not mistaken, in the same book of De  Carmo I had found that the Poincare metric is the left invariant metric of this Lie group. How youthink that the isometry group(Holomorphic automorphisms) is discrete?

Comment: Oh, never mind, I was confused. I still think the term "upper half plane with its standard nonabelian Lie group structure" is pretty confusing, though.

Comment: I received an anwer in MO  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/209147/certain-principal-bundle-structure-on-mathbbrn-setminus-0